# Google Document "shrunk" while editing

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I was editing a Google Document and I hit something on my keyboard that made all of the text really small and the document also shrunk.  How do I fix this?

Comment: The menus shrunk as well? Or just the document?

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> will zoom you out of a webpage in most browsers. Perhaps it was that you pressed?

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in again or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset your zoom settings.